# How to delete all emails from a mailbox on iPhone

Tags: iphone

How do I delete all emails on my iPhone4 from a mailbox without selecting them one at a time?  On the last iPhone OS update, something changed which caused all of my old emails to be re-downloaded to my phone.  I have about 3500 emails all but the last few days' I need to delete.

Comment: Tried using the solution from "How can I 'Delete All' from Inbox mail folder in iOS 8.1" and the mail seems to be deleted but does not show up in the trash.  If I delete one at a time it shows up in the trash. When checking back in the mailbox, the count of 3500 disappears from the right of the mailbox name line.  After a few minutes, when looking back at the mailbox all of the mail is back, all 3500.  Will let this sit for a few hours to see if something is lagging and then post another comment as to whether it succeeded or failed as a solution.

Comment: Waited about an hour, all of the mail remained there but the strange things is the mailbox only shows the newest mail in the count of pieces of mail.  It shows 7 (new since I deleted all) but 3507 are still there.  I'll retry the procedure again tonight and see if I get a different result.

Comment: Here is what seems to happen.  The mail appears to be moved to the trash when I go through the first part of the procedure.  Then when I delete it from the trash, in the second part, it seems to be gone.  The count of mail in the mailbox goes to "null" like there is none there. But when I open the mailbox up, all of the mail is still there even though it was gone in the first step.  After about an hour the sync icon stops turning but all of the main remains and the trash is empty

Comment: I tried another experiment - swiping across a piece of mail (not opening it) and clicking on the delete button.  It moves to the trash.  Deleting all trash and it is gone from both the trash and the mail.  I increased the sample size to 10, then 100, then 250 and they all get deleted like they should.  So the basic delete mechanism seems to work.

Comment: I also logged onto the email providers email web portal and deleted all of the mail, so at least it can't be brought down again.  Now my problem is to simply delete the ones on the Iphone, which grew from 3500 to just over 10,000.

Comment: Buscar - Thanks for your comment about the steps, but it didn't seem to work.